# Live-preview lines filtered with a stack of filters?

Tags: search, regex

I would like to have a *live preview* of a filtered plain text lines. It is important that multiple filters need to be applied either exclusively or inclusively (similar to the filters in [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)). After filtering is ready, I would like to be able to export the result.

I could achieve similar with `grep "filter1\|filter2\|filter3` but some of my greps are buggy and it is hard to maintain this kind of filters there are plenty filters. Live preview is not easily achieved either, because `| head` is only a few lines and with `| less` where I can do text search, I'm not sure if I can save the result. (Also it's a bit inconvenient with pipeline, even if I like command line.)

For a different user experience, I could use something more visual (although prefer minimal).

Answer (score 2):

Look what I made for you, cute little naxa :)

[image: running on /proc/cpuinfo]

The above is the result of running `python3 live-line-filter.py /proc/cpuinfo` with the filters you see in the screenshot above.

Reading from stdin would be nice, but it's hard because Qt does not seem to support it. I guess you could do it in plain Python, run the Qt app in another thread, and have Qt listen on a socket (and feed it from the Python main thread)... Too much work for a tiny improvement. I guess you already have your data if you want to try live filters.

On Ubuntu, you can install python3-pyqt4 to get PyQt (which is needed).

live-line-filter.py:

```
from PyQt4 import Qt
import sys
import fileinput
import re

class LiveLineFilterApplication(Qt.QApplication):

    def __init__(self, args):
        Qt.QApplication.__init__(self, args)
        self.addWidgets()

        self.unfilteredlines = [x for x in fileinput.input()]

        self.slotRefilter()

        self.exec_()

    def addWidgets(self):
        self.w = Qt.QWidget()
        self.layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self.w)

        self.input = Qt.QTextEdit(".*", None)
        self.input.textChanged.connect(self.slotRefilter)

        self.textedit = Qt.QTextEdit("pending", None)
        self.textedit.setReadOnly(True)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.input)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.textedit)
        self.w.show()

    def slotRefilter(self):
        filters = self.input.toPlainText().strip()
        matches = self.unfilteredlines
        for filt in filters.split("\n"):
          if filt == "": continue
          r = re.compile(filt)
          matches = [x for x in matches if r.search(x)]
        self.textedit.setText("".join(matches))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = LiveLineFilterApplication(sys.argv)
```

Alternatives:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/89718/309483

Comment: @naxa: no, i was just trying to freak you out :P. Tell me if the program works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Software requests are off topic here. However, as a workaround, you could use grep's `-f` flag:

```
   -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.   The
          empty   file   contains   zero  patterns,  and
          therefore matches nothing.  (-f  is  specified
          by POSIX.)
```

Comment: didn't know it's off-topic. there is a tag `software-rec`. => ??? btw thanks for noting!

Comment: @naxa Yes, there's a tag but tags can be created by anyone, see [here](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic), this falls under "product recommendation".

Comment: @terdon: No, not anyone. [You need 300 rep](http://superuser.com/privileges/create-tags).

Comment: @naxa it's on topic for questions about a particular problem (read: anything but "What program can do this?").  From the [tag:software-rec] tag: `Important: It's often better to ask for a real problem instead of a software to solve it`.  So in this case, it would have been better to simply ask how it's possible to combine regular expressions, or inquire as to how the grep tool could be used to stack filters (the general ideology of that still falls under the general UNIX philosophy).

Comment: I see, thank you very much! I seek user experience here, not mere 'functionality', since it would add meaningful value for me. (Thinking loudly : this should be valid right, since otherwise I would only need `cat` and `gcc`, not even grep). I better word it torwards the user experience then.

Comment: @Breakthrough I edited my question in an attempt to better reflect the experience I was looking for.

Comment: @naxa you might want to have a look at an online regex tester (like [this one](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)), as they often provide a nice visualization for prototyping regular expressions.